# TaskCompleteSource with 2 different types?

Tags: c#

I have `ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<SomeRandomClass>` but I'm in a case where the dictionary should be able to add also `TaskCompletionSource<Task>` is there a way to do that without having separate `ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<Task>>` ? Right now I'm using 2 `Dictionaries` but I'm thinking of a way to `add and remove` from the dictionary of both `TaskCompletionSource` ? Tried using `TaskCompletionSource<Type>` but seems to not work.

**Example**

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<TestClass>> directory = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<TestClass>>();

// first case
var task = new TaskCompletionSource<TestClass>();
var id = "2312-43d-asd-fsd-sda"
directory.TryAdd(id, task); // works

// second case
var task = new TaskCompletionSource<Task>();
var id = "321-23-sad-21-3-123";
directory.TryAdd(id, task); // doesn't work, different type
```

Comment: May be you could provide some code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Why do you need a `TaskCompletionSource<Task>`?

Comment: Because there is a cases where when I get the response I should resolve the task only without returning anything.

Comment: Why can't you use `TaskCompletionSource<TestClass>` for both cases? Task<T> inherits Task so you can just expose Task for those cases which don't require a result. It's impossible to use different value types in the same dictionary unless you fall back to `object` type which is unlikely option you want to go with.

Comment: Hm, I don't get your point. I have methods which when the `Task` is resolved the return type of the method is `TestClass` and the other ones where they should `await` only the return type is `Task`. Can you provide simple example of what are you saying?

Comment: [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/03pX2i) is example. The `TaskCompletionSource` is used in both `Task<int>` and `Task` methods.

Comment: Well.. this is going to work I guess and saves my case. If you want write it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: What's a  **`ConcurrentDirectory`**?

Comment: Fixed it, sorry :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to sum up the discussion in the comments the problem is more related to generalization of an approach which would allow to work with a `TaskCompletionSource` suitable for `Task<T>` and `Task` cases. Since there is no non-generic `TaskCompletionSource` implementation as possible solution using `TaskCompletionSource<SomeClass>` for both scenarios with awaiting of tasks with result and without results can be suggested. It's possible because `Task<T>` inherits `Task` which allows to return more basic class as an awaitable. The example below demontrates this:

```
    static Task<int> WithResult()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            tcs.SetResult(2222);
        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    static Task WithNoResult()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            tcs.SetResult(default(int)); 
        });
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    static async Task InitiateTasks()
    {
        var result = await WithResult();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        await WithNoResult();
        Console.WriteLine("No result");
    }
```